# why do RSU start sending BSM messages to nodes after it receives scheduled self-message even though I didn't implement any BSM sending

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm trying to learn veins, this is the initialization in the RSU application class :

```
void rsuApp::initialize(int stage) {
   BaseWaveApplLayer::initialize(stage);
   if(stage == 0){
       event = new cMessage("event");
       EV << "Scheduling first send to t=5.0s\n";
       scheduleAt(200.0, event);
   }
}
```

I scheduled a self-message at second 200
this is the handleSelfMsg() function code:

```
void rsuApp::handleSelfMsg(cMessage* msg) {
    BaseWaveApplLayer::handleSelfMsg(msg);
    findHost()->getDisplayString().updateWith("r=360,pink");
}
```

during simulation before the rsu receives the selfMsg (before second 200 ) nothing happened but when the RSU receives the self message at second 200 it starts to sends BSM to other nodes even though i didn't implement any BSM sending

I don't know if BSM and beacons are the same things but I set the sendBeacons parameter in omnetpp.ini to false but the RSU still send BSM messages after receiving the self message

`*.rsu[*].appl.sendBeacons = false`

so I want to know why the RSU start sending BSM to other nodes after receiving the self message 
is there a relation between scheduled events and BSM?

Comment: Which Veins version do you use?

Comment: i'm using veins 4.7.1

Answer (score 1):

In your method `handleSelfMsg` you call [`BaseWaveApplLayer::handleSelfMsg(msg)`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.7.1/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.cc#L237). This method is populating and transmitting a Basic Safety Message (BSM) as a broadcast to all other nodes in the scenario.

`sendBeacons` just controls whether this is being done regularly in order to send periodic beacons. If enabled, the same method as above is called and a BSM is transmitted (see [here](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.7.1/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.cc#L105)).